# Ignore SSL errors with signalR Core Client

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr.client

I'm making an application that involves a website on localhost as a user interface with Asp.net Core and SignalR Core.

My problem is that I get an authentication exception when starting the connection.
I know this happens because I haven't ran `dotnet dev-certs https --trust`. But I can't expect an average user to run this command or have the dotnet SDK installed at all.

I've tried using

```cs
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
```

in my Startup.cs (and other places, but I understand that it's a global setting. in any case it was executed before the HubConnection)
to no avail.
I also tried setting a new HttpMessageHandlerFactory, but the documentation tells me that doesnt affect Websockets.

I don't believe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38138952/bypass-invalid-ssl-certificate-in-net-core) is a solution, because I can't use a different HttpClient (unless I'm mistaken)

As you can see, I'm not connecting to https at all:

```cs
connection = new HubConnectionBuilder().WithUrl("http://localhost:5000/MiniLyokoHub" ).Build();
```

So I don't see why it is even trying to get the certificate.

Here is the full error: 
https://pastebin.com/1ELbeWtc

How can I get around this issue?
I don't need a certificate, since the user will be connecting to their own localhost. 
Or should I just not use websockets?

Comment: You are neither supposed to run websites locally in production, nor to use the dev cert on client machines.

Comment: Just a question: if the user is connecting always to localhost, why https at all? Wouldnt plain http suffice?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [bypass invalid SSL certificate in .net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38138952/bypass-invalid-ssl-certificate-in-net-core)

Comment: @ZorgoZ it would suffice, and I'm connecting to the http port, but it still throws an exception

Comment: That's strange. Remember: secure SignalR will first try to use WSS instead of WS, not https or http. Check developer console for the actual protocol.

Comment: @ZorgoZ Where can I find the protocol? edited the post with some more information

Answer (score 35, accepted):

When connecting to HTTPS, to always recognise the SSL certificate as successfully verified in the SignalR Core client you should do this in `HttpMessageHandlerFactory` configs. Use `HttpConnectionOptions` in `WithUrl` method like this:

```cs
connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
.WithUrl("https://localhost:443/MiniLyokoHub", (opts) =>
{
    opts.HttpMessageHandlerFactory = (message) =>
    {
        if (message is HttpClientHandler clientHandler)
            // always verify the SSL certificate
            clientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback +=
                (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; };
        return message;
    };
})
.Build();
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Exactly what I as someone who is using HTTPS was looking for!

Comment: I tried many other approaches and this was the only one that worked. This works as a workaround if you're running a .NET Core app (that has a SignalR hub) in Docker using Linux containers. In my case, I successfully set up my .NET Core app that creates the SignalR hub, so that the app used https using the .NET Core self-signed developer certificate, but for some reason when the SignalR hub is running a Linux Docker container, any client connection to the SignalR hub was giving the error `The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure`.

Comment: Was having some trouble getting a Xamarin.Forms app to connect to a blazor hub hosted locally and this helped

Comment: It looks like this solution is helping a lot of people, so I'm going to mark it as the accepted solution.

Comment: This is incomplete. You also need to set `opts.WebSocketConfiguration = wsc => wsc.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, certificate, chain, policyErrors) => true;`, else the websocket will fail and you'll get a "server disconnected before ... somthing" error.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that the SignalR Core Client is also subject to *Https redirection*
Which is why it wouldn't connect to the http port.

For my use case, I just had to disable it in Startup.cs

Comment: how did you disable that?

Comment: @pregmatch it's been forever but I believe you're looking for `app.UseHttpsRedirection();`. If you remove that line, it wont redirect https. That being said it looks like the top voted answer might help you better

Answer (score 0):

When connecting using HTTPS, to always recognise the SSL certificate as successfully verified in the SignalR Core client, you need to add the following so that it is verified *for both http and wss*:

```
var connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
    .WithUrl("https://localhost:443/MiniLyokoHub", (opts) =>
    {
        opts.HttpMessageHandlerFactory = (message) =>
        {
            if (message is HttpClientHandler clientHandler)
                // always verify the SSL certificate
                clientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback +=
                (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; };
            return message;
        };
        options.WebSocketConfiguration = wsc => wsc.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, certificate, chain, policyErrors) => true;
    })
    .Build();
```